# SmartGWT ListGrid is slow, but only in Internet Explorer

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, gwt, grid, smartgwt

We have migrated from gwtext to SmartGWT and overall the experience is Ok. However, we have big problems with the ListGrid component of SmartGWT.

It is very slow if both of the following conditions are met:

- Internet Explorer is used
- 5 or more columns

the speed will decrease if you add more columns up to the point where the whole thing is unusable and you have to kill the browser, e.g. through the windows task manager.

Grids with 1 column are fine in internet explorer

Grids with a large number of columns are fine in Firefox, opera

In the SmartGWT forums I've found two entries that are about this problem, but none of the suggested workarounds has fixed the problem.

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=5896

Since I am only allowed to post one hyperlink, here's the number of the second thread:

t=5193

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Put a link on your website that says, "This page displaying slowly? Get a real web browser: www.firefox.com". Since the issue is with IE's poor handling of grids, you might as well make it clear that the user's experience will improve if they get a better browser. Give credit where credit is due...

Comment: nice one :) but unfortunately not an option. BTW I hate all browsers, maybe opera a little less than firefox and firefox a little less than ie, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Can you list out the actual steps you took to make sure you followed all the suggestions in the threads in the SmartClient forums?

If you look at the SmartGWT Showcase LiveGrid sample:

```
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_live
```

Is this slow for you?  If so possibly something is wrong with your machine or browser and you should try a co-worker's machine.

Comment: We've tested other machine and all exposed the same behaviour - ff fast, ie slow.

The LiveGrid sample is much snappier on ff than on ie. However, ie is still ok with this sample.

We've been fiddling around with grid settings - setBaseStyle("tallCell") and setShowRollover(false) have improved the performance slightly.

We're upgraded to latest&greatest GWT (1.6.4), SmartGWT (1.1), Java (Update 14); other javascript/ajax libs have been removed; browser cache cleared.

Reduced number of rows, no impact; slow even with 5 rows.

Even copied the livegrid sample 1:1 into my code, still slow.

Comment: Several more steps are listed at the SmartClient forums, but first a sanity check: you seem to be saying that a purely client-side interaction runs faster at smartclient.com than on your server.  That doesn't make sense.  What interactions, specifically, are slow?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I.E. 8 handles horribly more than one or two buttons in a page (input type=button or button tags). I don't know if listgrid makes any use of that but if it does there is no workaround. Use something that uses divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grid's `setFastCellUpdates(true);`