# GWT & IE8 cause a very laggy table-behavior

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

I've yet another question. I'm working with GWT 2.0.4 and IE8 as well as FireFox (the latter only for comparison purpose). My application needs to load data and show it inside a table. There are about 60 columns and 150 rows to show.

Since the loading is dynamic - as soon as a dataset has been fetched, it's added to the table - I'm fine with slowdowns during loading process. However: when the table is completely loaded, I'd expect it to be pretty snappy and let me scroll it without much lag.

While the loaded table reacts in FireFox pretty good - it stays very responsive - Internet Explorer 8 is causing me a lot of headaches. In particular: as soon as the table finished loading and I try to scroll around or highlight a row, IE8 becomes VERY laggy and highlighting a row makes IE8 consume 50+% of CPU power.

I am not using any 3rd-party libraries and even displaying empty cells in a FlexTable still gives me the same issue.

I found some probably related issue here: [SmartGWT ListGrid is slow, but only in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070856/smartgwt-listgrid-is-slow-but-only-in-internet-explorer) . Unfortunately neither the issue there, nor the supplied links for SmartGWT solved my problem as I am not using SmartGWT. I do believe though that the problem is related.

I'd be happy to try any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible (and your description of the problem suggests so), use [`Grid`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) instead:

> A rectangular grid that can contain
>   text, html, or a child Widget within
>   its cells. **It must be resized
>   explicitly to the desired number of
>   rows and columns.**

Have a look at [bulk table renderers](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/BulkTableRenderers) @ [GWT Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/) for a comparison of these approaches (it's a little dated, but the point that `FlexTable` is slower than `Grid` still holds ;)). The "bulk rendered" tables from the incubator are also an option, however keep in mind that those widgets might not be maintained any more (and for example, contain bugs) - or are rapidly maintained :D But looking at the source might at least point you in the right direction, if you wanted to roll out your own solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'Ve already found the BulkTableRenderer and I am now messing around with the PaginationScrollTable. It seems to be exactly what I need. It's all but easy to use nor are there any trivial examples - and they'd be very useful, because it's quite difficult to use that PaginationScrollTable. You have to specify a TableModel and a TableDefinition (columns) as well as overwrite certain abstract methods etc... Thank you very much though :)

Comment: If `PaginationScrollTable` caught your attention, they I'd recommend the latest GWT 2.1 milestone - it should contain the new Data Presentation widgets, which were created using experience gained from the (now unsupported and dropped) `PaginationScrollTable` (and probably some other tables from the incubator). You'll probably also have hard time finding good documentation and examples (can't say for sure, haven't checked lately), but it's a "safer" bet than `PaginationScrollTable`, IMHO.

Comment: See the [Bikeshed](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/branches/2.1/bikeshed) and it's [samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/branches/2.1/bikeshed/src/com/google/gwt/sample/bikeshed) for a starting point :) (sorry for double post, but the links made the comment too long)

Answer (score 0):

> highlighting a row makes IE8 consume 50+% of CPU power.

Maybe it's because you added mouse listeners to every row in your table. If so you could use `:hover`-pseudo-class in your css-files.

This article maybe helpful if you need to handle Events from a bunch of widgets in your table: http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_UI.html#As_the_application_grows,_event_handlers_seem_to_fire_more_slowl

Comment: Hey there :), I already checked that. I am using css :hover pseudo class in my css instead of using JavaScript. However: the problem still remains. I think that the problem lies in the way the IE javascript engine performs DOM-operations. Creating a huge table in pure HTML works fine, while causing serious lagging problems if created using JavaScript. I'll be trying the BulkTableRenderer and the associated classes (see the other answer above :) ). Thank you for your response though.

Comment: `:hover` is a great advice and everybody should be using it but... [IE6 doesn't support it for non-links](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16) ;_; Unless, of course, your target doesn't include IE6, in which case, you are a happy web developer and can do all the cool stuff ;)